# Iam trying to post text in facebook wall using below code but that code is not posted...please help me

Tags: android

Iam trying to post text in facebook wall using below code but that code is not posted.

```
public static boolean shareViaFacebook(Context ctx, String text) 
     {

         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
             return true;
         }

         Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
         Log.d("", "Sample Text*****"+text);
         sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ""+text);
         sharingIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
         try 
         {
             ctx.startActivity(Intent
                     .createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
         }
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
```

**strong text**

Comment: try using Facebook sdk for Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps in : [Facebook sdk for android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

You can build great, native sharing experiences for people using your app using below coding lines .

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
        .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
        .build();
```